# Compile JInput on ARM

Tags: java, linux, java-native-interface

I have a Raspberry Pi 2, and an arduino pro micro set up as a Joystick. On the Pi i have a java application that runs well on a PC with both Linux and Windows with the arduino joystick connected. But as soon as I start running the program on the pi I get an error message like:

```
`Failed to load library:" /libjinput-linux64.so: /libjinput-linux64.so`
```

After some googling around i find that the problem is that the Jinput library is not compiled to run on ARM processors:

[JInput on RaspberryPi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851911/jinput-on-raspberrypi)

So far so good, but this far I could not find a solution as to how I get the `.so` file compiled to run on the arm processor. I guess it is somewhat trivial for someone with the knowledge, since the file is easily decompiled and the project is open source.

But I have been stuck at this stage for the last 1½ month. Any help as to how to compile it where to find the files that are to be compiled and such, or alternatively finding an already compiled file for the raspberry pi 2 would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer about how to compile JNI libraries, but there appears to be a pre-compiled version available on Raspbian:

```
> apt search jinput
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libjinput-java/stable 20100502+dfsg-7 all
  Java Game Controller API

libjinput-java-doc/stable 20100502+dfsg-7 all
  Java Game Controller API (javadoc)

libjinput-jni/stable 20100502+dfsg-7 armhf
  Java Game Controller API (jni)
```

So the solution may be to just `apt install libjinput-java`; this will probably include the `-jni` package as a dependency ([see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286672/25985)).

Comment: I have to check this out tonight - But if it is that easy you just made my week.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Gave up on the project around 3 years ago though, someone else might have solved it.

Comment: I can add that i have tried with other joysticks beside the arduino, to rule out the fact that i might have made a mistake with the arduino, or jinput is not compatible with the arduino.